# Stuck in Vector in Java

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I created a string vector and I want to store the selected type of coffee in the vector, for example if I choose number 3,4,5 and 1,  store them in Vector1 the variables ("LATTE", "AMERICAN", "CAPUCCINO" and "MOKA") and  print those stored names, but the problem is that it just prints, number 6 "BLACK", always.

```
 import java.io.*;

    class Exercise{

        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
            DataInputStream receivedata= new DataInputStream(System.in);
            String keyboard; 
                int seleccafe,n=0,contvector=0;
                String []Vector1=new String[200];

                            do{

                                 System.out.println("\n1. MOKA");
                                 System.out.println("2. EXPRESO");
                                 System.out.println("3. LATTE");
                                 System.out.println("4. AMERICAN");
                                 System.out.println("5. CAPUCCINO");
                                 System.out.println("6. BLACK");
                                 System.out.println("0. OUT");
                                 System.out.print("\nTYPE THE NUMBER: ");

                                 seleccafe=Read_Da("");
                                 SelectCo(Vector1,seleccafe,n);

                                 contvector++;
                                 n++;
                                 if(seleccafe==0) break;

                            }while(true);

                                for(int i=0; i<contvector-1; i++){
                                System.out.println(Vector1[i]);
                                }

        }
            public static int  Read_Da (String TxtMsg) throws java.io.IOException{
                int X=0;
                String keyboard;
                DataInputStream reveivedata= new DataInputStream(System.in);
                do{
                    System.out.print("");
                    keyboard=reveivedata.readLine();
                    try{
                        X=Integer.parseInt(keyboard);
                        if(X<0){
                            System.out.println("SELECT JUST 0+");
                            continue;
                        }
                        return X; 
                    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                        System.out.println("JUST NUMBERS");         
                    }
                }while(true);
        }

        public static void SelectCo(String xVector[], int xseleccafe, int xi){

            switch(xseleccafe){
                case 1:
                    xVector[xi]= "MOKA";
                case 2: 
                    xVector[xi]="EXPRESSO";
                case 3: 
                    xVector[xi]="LATE";
                case 4: 
                    xVector[xi]="AMERICAN ";
                case 5:
                    xVector[xi]="CAPUCCINO"; 
                case 6: 
                    xVector[xi]="BLACK";
            }
        }

    }
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You should debug your application. Add some prints to see what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are missing the word `break;` after each `case` clause in `SelectCo`, so each `case` is "falling through" to the one below, and finishing with `case 6:`.

It should look like this.

```
      switch(xseleccafe){
            case 1:
                xVector[xi]= "MOKA";
                break;
            case 2: 
                xVector[xi]="EXPRESSO";
                break;
            case 3: 
                xVector[xi]="LATE";
                break;
            case 4: 
                xVector[xi]="AMERICAN ";
                break;
            case 5:
                xVector[xi]="CAPUCCINO"; 
                break;
            case 6: 
                xVector[xi]="BLACK";
                break;
            default:
                xVector[xi]="UNKNOWN";
        }
```

More detail [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)